# Как правильно вывести данные из таблицы sql в текст телеграм бота?

Tags: python, sql, telegram, бот, telebot

sql:

```
def user_status(self,user_id):
    cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM user_info WHERE user_id = ?",(user_id,))
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    log = []
    for str in records:
        log.append(str[-1])
    print(log)
    conn.close()
```

python:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'С Возвращением,'+str(db.user_status(message.chat.id)))
```

В телеграме получаю:

```
С Возвращением,None
```

Comment: Крайне не рекомендуется давать переменным имена, совпадающие с именами встроенных типов питона (`str`). Когда совсем невтерпёж :)  добавляйте в конце нижнее подчеркивание. Ну а в БД у Вас, кстати, точно не `str`, а `row`. И зачем брать `[-1]`, если в таблице всего одна колонка, т.е. `[0]` ?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас функция `user_status` ничего не возвращает (т.е. `None`). Вероятно, в ней должна вернуться какая-то строка, например, `return ", ".join(log)`

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогло